# Are lambda functions recommended than having an EC2 instance run 24/7 in a loop?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I have a python program that scrapes news articles and puts them in a database; It's structured somewhat like:

```py
while(true):
    try:
        getAPnews();
        getReutersNews();
        time.sleep(60 * 5); # Sleeps for 5 mins
    catch:
        continue
```

So it performs a function goes to sleep for 5 mins, and repeats in a big `try-catch` block; It doesn't need any input, just does everything on its own.

I've been using Google's EC2 instance to run this 24/7, but it's been costly, costing me ~$60 for this very non-demanding task that takes around 1 ~ 3% of the entire CPU utilization. I heard that for functions that only needed to be run in a certain amount of time, AWS Lambda is very efficient & cheap for getting things done like this. So here's my question:

- What kind of restructuring is required to convert from regular Python loop to a 'lambda function'?
- What kind of features that are provided by lambda functions pertinent to my purposes?

Comment: Change your question so it will not be "on hold" and people will be able to answer you. Ask like "How to schedule lambda function to run every 5 min".

Comment: @Azize I did, it's waiting for approval.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'd like to add that this question is falsely marked as "primarily opinion-based", because it's not. There is a very clear answer here, which is Lambda is the correct choice for running a service that runs every 5 minutes and checks a status, you will end up saving a lot this way.